# Swift UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath incorrect set cell content

Tags: swift, swift2, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHW95.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ9SI.png)

I want to make the button hidden just if its title equals the 'str' variable.

I can not add more photos but it's doing the same for "7:00", "12:00", "17:00", "22:00" values. 
Just want for "2:00" and doing comparison for that.

Is this a (collectionView)cellForItemAtIndexPath bug or anything else? I'm so confused. Please help..

Comment: just show what you tried

Comment: There is two pictures showing my code block and output. I want to make horizontal collectionview just having button inside to show 24hours like "01:00", "02:00", "..". But want to set some of the buttons different from the others. It'll be hide button or different titleColor. This example, I try to hide button which has "02:00" title

Comment: .. But some other buttons are also change which has "7:00", "12:00", "17:00" titles. And when I move the horizontal collectionview to the left or right , each time it set different button. This is strange, isnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scrolling it will re use the cell so you set hidden true false based on condition. i think this is your issue.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let hour = array[indexPath.row]
let str ="2:00"
 if(cell.hourBtn.titleLabel?.text ==str {
   cell.hourBtn.hidden = true
 }
  else {
   cell.hourBtn.hidden = false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no bug in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, its you that hiding the `label` of cell. So it just hide the label not remove the cell. If you want to display only that value that is not equal to `2:00` then you need to create one extra array for that and give it to the `CollectionViewDelegate` methods. Create one global array and function like this.

```
var array: [Int] = [Int]()
fun populateData() {
    for i in oldArray {
        if i != 2 {
            self.array.append(i)
        }
    }
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Now use this `array` object in `CollectionViewDelegate` methods like this

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return self.array.count
} 

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let hour = array[indexPath.row]
    cell.hourBtn.setTitle("\(hour):00", forState: .Normal)
    //Now there is no need to write code for hiding button
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Its working but what can I do if I want to show that button but just want to set its color different from the others? When I try to set its color different and try to moved the horizontal collectionview right2left or left2right, constantly updating buttons color and each time shifting different button and not that I want.

Comment: Don't understand what you try to say. Explain briefly. Which button color you want to change?

Comment: According to your solution, there is an array including some hours. But I want to show all hours some has different qualities. And when I moved collectionview, each time it changing different buttons color. So apparently, its all about ''else'' :).